# Communicating with Windows7 Display API

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling

I have yet failed to find a decent(ANYTHING really) pinvoke wrapper around new win7 CCD api.
The api can be found itself from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh406259(v=vs.85).aspx

I've spend few hours converting structures/method calls, so that I could use it from C#.

Here is the first "draft":

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CONVERTING_CCD
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class takes care of wrapping "Connecting and Configuring Displays(CCD) Win32 API"
    /// Author Erti-Chris Eelmaa || easter199 at hotmail dot com
    /// </summary>
    public class CCDWrapper
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct LUID
        {
            public uint LowPart;
            public uint HighPart;
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum DisplayConfigVideoOutputTechnology : uint
        {
            Other = 4294967295, // -1
            Hd15 = 0,
            Svideo = 1,
            CompositeVideo = 2,
            ComponentVideo = 3,
            Dvi = 4,
            Hdmi = 5,
            Lvds = 6,
            DJpn = 8,
            Sdi = 9,
            DisplayportExternal = 10,
            DisplayportEmbedded = 11,
            UdiExternal = 12,
            UdiEmbedded = 13,
            Sdtvdongle = 14,
            Internal = 0x80000000,
            ForceUint32 = 0xFFFFFFFF
        }

        #region SdcFlags enum

        [Flags]
        public enum SdcFlags : uint
        {
            Zero = 0,

            TopologyInternal = 0x00000001,
            TopologyClone = 0x00000002,
            TopologyExtend = 0x00000004,
            TopologyExternal = 0x00000008,
            TopologySupplied = 0x00000010,

            UseSuppliedDisplayConfig = 0x00000020,
            Validate = 0x00000040,
            Apply = 0x00000080,
            NoOptimization = 0x00000100,
            SaveToDatabase = 0x00000200,
            AllowChanges = 0x00000400,
            PathPersistIfRequired = 0x00000800,
            ForceModeEnumeration = 0x00001000,
            AllowPathOrderChanges = 0x00002000,

            UseDatabaseCurrent = TopologyInternal | TopologyClone | TopologyExtend | TopologyExternal
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum DisplayConfigFlags : uint
        {
            Zero = 0x0,
            PathActive = 0x00000001
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum DisplayConfigSourceStatus
        {
            Zero = 0x0,
            InUse = 0x00000001
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum DisplayConfigTargetStatus : uint
        {
            Zero = 0x0,

            InUse                         = 0x00000001,
            FORCIBLE                       = 0x00000002,
            ForcedAvailabilityBoot       = 0x00000004,
            ForcedAvailabilityPath       = 0x00000008,
            ForcedAvailabilitySystem     = 0x00000010,
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum DisplayConfigRotation : uint
        {
            Zero = 0x0,

            Identity = 1,
            Rotate90 = 2,
            Rotate180 = 3,
            Rotate270 = 4,
            ForceUint32 = 0xFFFFFFFF
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum DisplayConfigPixelFormat : uint
        {
            Zero = 0x0,

            Pixelformat8Bpp = 1,
            Pixelformat16Bpp = 2,
            Pixelformat24Bpp = 3,
            Pixelformat32Bpp = 4,
            PixelformatNongdi = 5,
            PixelformatForceUint32 = 0xffffffff
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum DisplayConfigScaling : uint
        {
            Zero = 0x0, 

            Identity = 1,
            Centered = 2,
            Stretched = 3,
            Aspectratiocenteredmax = 4,
            Custom = 5,
            Preferred = 128,
            ForceUint32 = 0xFFFFFFFF
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct DisplayConfigRational
        {
            public uint numerator;
            public uint denominator;
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum DisplayConfigScanLineOrdering : uint
        {
            Unspecified = 0,
            Progressive = 1,
            Interlaced = 2,
            InterlacedUpperfieldfirst = Interlaced,
            InterlacedLowerfieldfirst = 3,
            ForceUint32 = 0xFFFFFFFF
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct DisplayConfigPathInfo
        {
            public DisplayConfigPathSourceInfo sourceInfo;
            public DisplayConfigPathTargetInfo targetInfo;
            public uint flags;
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum DisplayConfigModeInfoType : uint
        {
            Zero = 0,

            Source = 1,
            Target = 2,
            ForceUint32 = 0xFFFFFFFF
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
        public struct DisplayConfigModeInfo
        {
            [FieldOffset((0))]
            public DisplayConfigModeInfoType infoType;

            [FieldOffset(4)]
            public uint id;

            [FieldOffset(8)]
            public LUID adapterId;

            [FieldOffset(16)]
            public DisplayConfigTargetMode targetMode;

            [FieldOffset(16)]
            public DisplayConfigSourceMode sourceMode;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct DisplayConfig2DRegion
        {
            public uint cx;
            public uint cy;
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum D3DmdtVideoSignalStandard : uint
        {
            Uninitialized = 0,
            VesaDmt = 1,
            VesaGtf = 2,
            VesaCvt = 3,
            Ibm = 4,
            Apple = 5,
            NtscM = 6,
            NtscJ = 7,
            Ntsc443 = 8,
            PalB = 9,
            PalB1 = 10,
            PalG = 11,
            PalH = 12,
            PalI = 13,
            PalD = 14,
            PalN = 15,
            PalNc = 16,
            SecamB = 17,
            SecamD = 18,
            SecamG = 19,
            SecamH = 20,
            SecamK = 21,
            SecamK1 = 22,
            SecamL = 23,
            SecamL1 = 24,
            Eia861 = 25,
            Eia861A = 26,
            Eia861B = 27,
            PalK = 28,
            PalK1 = 29,
            PalL = 30,
            PalM = 31,
            Other = 255
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct DisplayConfigVideoSignalInfo
        {
            public long pixelRate;
            public DisplayConfigRational hSyncFreq;
            public DisplayConfigRational vSyncFreq;
            public DisplayConfig2DRegion activeSize;
            public DisplayConfig2DRegion totalSize;

            public D3DmdtVideoSignalStandard videoStandard;
            public DisplayConfigScanLineOrdering ScanLineOrdering;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct DisplayConfigTargetMode
        {
            public DisplayConfigVideoSignalInfo targetVideoSignalInfo;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct PointL
        {
            public int x;
            public int y;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct DisplayConfigSourceMode
        {
            public uint width;
            public uint height;
            public DisplayConfigPixelFormat pixelFormat;
            public PointL position;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct DisplayConfigPathSourceInfo
        {
            public LUID adapterId;
            public uint id;
            public uint modeInfoIdx;

            public DisplayConfigSourceStatus statusFlags;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct DisplayConfigPathTargetInfo
        {
            public LUID adapterId;
            public uint id;
            public uint modeInfoIdx;
            public DisplayConfigVideoOutputTechnology outputTechnology; 
            public DisplayConfigRotation rotation;
            public DisplayConfigScaling scaling;
            public DisplayConfigRational refreshRate;
            public DisplayConfigScanLineOrdering scanLineOrdering;

            public bool targetAvailable;
            public DisplayConfigTargetStatus statusFlags;
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum QueryDisplayFlags : uint
        {
            Zero = 0x0,

            AllPaths = 0x00000001,
            OnlyActivePaths = 0x00000002,
            DatabaseCurrent = 0x00000004
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum DisplayConfigTopologyId : uint
        {
            Zero = 0x0,

            Internal = 0x00000001,
            Clone = 0x00000002,
            Extend = 0x00000004,
            External = 0x00000008,
            ForceUint32 = 0xFFFFFFFF
        }


        #endregion

        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern int SetDisplayConfig(uint numPathArrayElements, out DisplayConfigPathInfo pathArray,
                                                  uint numModeInfoArrayElements, out DisplayConfigModeInfo modeInfoArray,
                                                  SdcFlags flags);

        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern int QueryDisplayConfig(QueryDisplayFlags flags, ref int numPathArrayElements,
                                                ref DisplayConfigPathInfo[] pathInfoArray, 
                                                ref int modeInfoArrayElements,
                                                ref DisplayConfigModeInfo[] modeInfoArray,
                                                IntPtr z);

        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern int GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes(QueryDisplayFlags flags, out int numPathArrayElements, out int numModeInfoArrayElements);
    }
}
```

I am almost done, and when it's finished, I will send it to pinvoke.net. There is a problem right now, namely when I call QueryDisplayConfig(), null-reference exception will be thrown, that doesn't tell me anything at all. I've spent few hours rechecking everything, from back to forward, from forward to back.

Here is the actual code usage:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int numPathArrayElements;
    int numModeInfoArrayElements;

    // query active paths from the current computer.
    if (CCDWrapper.GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes(CCDWrapper.QueryDisplayFlags.OnlyActivePaths, out numPathArrayElements,
                                                   out numModeInfoArrayElements) == 0)
    {
        // 0 is success.
        var pathInfoArray = new CCDWrapper.DisplayConfigPathInfo[numPathArrayElements];
        var modeInfoArray = new CCDWrapper.DisplayConfigModeInfo[numModeInfoArrayElements];
        CCDWrapper.DisplayConfigTopologyId currentTopologyId; // don't use it right now.

        var first = Marshal.SizeOf(new CCDWrapper.DisplayConfigPathInfo());
        var second = Marshal.SizeOf(new CCDWrapper.DisplayConfigModeInfo());

        var status = CCDWrapper.QueryDisplayConfig(CCDWrapper.QueryDisplayFlags.OnlyActivePaths,
                                ref numPathArrayElements, ref pathInfoArray, ref numModeInfoArrayElements, 
                                ref modeInfoArray, IntPtr.Zero);

    }
}
```

Note that structure sizes should be proper:

```
var first = Marshal.SizeOf(new CCDWrapper.DisplayConfigPathInfo());
var second = Marshal.SizeOf(new CCDWrapper.DisplayConfigModeInfo());
```

first => 72,
second => 64,

and when I check it from C++:

```
int first = sizeof(DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO);
int second = sizeof(DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO);
```

it gives me the same result.

Comment: There is some similar code here: http://sources.team-mediaportal.com/svn/public/trunk/mediaportal/Core/Player/Windows7Helper.cs it may be useful to check what they do.

Comment: Is there any flag here I can use to know if the connected screen is powered On ? And if yes have you the complete working source of that somewhere ? (I know it's old ^^)

Comment: Ok the answer to my own question is yes : `targetInfo.targetAvailable`. You saved me man, is your code usable for comercial use as it is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your handling of the arrays in SetDisplayConfig and QueryDisplayConfig declarations are wrong. Try these changes:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern int SetDisplayConfig(
    uint numPathArrayElements, 
    [In] DisplayConfigPathInfo[] pathArray,
    uint numModeInfoArrayElements, 
    [In] DisplayConfigModeInfo[] modeInfoArray,
    SdcFlags flags
);

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern int QueryDisplayConfig(
    QueryDisplayFlags flags, 
    ref int numPathArrayElements,
    [Out] DisplayConfigPathInfo[] pathInfoArray, 
    ref int modeInfoArrayElements,
    [Out] DisplayConfigModeInfo[] modeInfoArray,
    IntPtr z
);
```