# Detect which monitor/display is being used out of two

Tags: c#, windows

I am currently working on a machine, which has 2 monitors on opposite sides of it. It has a joystick-like 4 buttons to control the movement of the mechanical hand in the center. They both display the same screen i.e. display 1 is duplicated on the 2nd screen. They both are touch-screen. I want them to work depending on which side user is (i.e pressing downward arrow on any screen should move the mechanical hand towards the user). Is there any way I can detect which monitor is being used programmatically (whichever user clicks on)?

Both screens have other info and things, so I can not create two different windows. I can make a button to choose which side user is on but I am keeping it as the second option.

Comment: Does this not resolve your query? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22258906/how-to-detect-duplicated-monitors-as-separate-screens?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: No, that question is about detecting if monitors are connected. In my case, I know both monitors are connected. I need to find out which is being used once the user touches/click on one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to reference System.Windows.Forms and System.Drawing framework DLLs.

We translate the screen from the current mouse position using below two lines

```
Screen s = Screen.FromPoint(new System.Drawing.Point(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X, System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y));
```

Let me know in case I have misunderstood your question and this is not what you were looking for.

Comment: I don't have access to machine today to try it out. I have a query since display is duplicated on both, the cursor will be on both screens simultaneously, so won't we get the same X and Y value if clicked on any screen?

Comment: It would consider both as the same screen and give the name of the screen which is the primary which is currently being duplicated.

Comment: Tried that, did not work. Implemented a toggle button instead.

Comment: @Ruturaj If this answer resolved your original question then please mark this as an answer. Thanks.