# C# Switch off or cover duplicated monitor

Tags: c#, screensaver

I'm developing an app in C#. This app will run on a PC and also in a WACOM tablet, which is a duplicated monitor of the PC.

I want to switch off or cover the tablet with an image because the client can't see the beginning and the end of the process. When the time is right, the tablet will turn on or the screensaver will be removed so that the client can interact and, once the client's actions are finished, the WACOM tablet returns to the initial state. How can I do this?

I've been searching and I've found how to switch off the principal [monitor](http://fci-h.blogspot.com.es/2007/03/turn-off-your-monitor-via-code-c.html)  but I don't know how to switch off only the tablet. Also some kind of screensaver would be right, but I didn't found how to put an image only in one screen.

Comment: It seems like a proper bounty question

Comment: How can I reward you? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Ofer! Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention the framework you are working, assuming you can reference Winforms, here is a way to show a form maximized on a specific screen:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Screen[] screens;
screens = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens;           
System.Windows.Forms.Screen selectedScreen = screens[1]; // choose your preferred monitor                 

// Sets the form to show maximized on the selected screen:

form.Left = currentScreen.Bounds.Width;
form.Top = currentScreen.Bounds.Height;
form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
form.Location = currentScreen.Bounds.Location;
Point p = new Point(currentScreen.Bounds.Location.X, currentScreen.Bounds.Location.Y);
form.Location = p;
form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
form.Show();
```

If you disable form borders and have a PictureBox docked to "Fill" displaying your selected image you will achieve your intended goal and cover your tablet screen with an image.

Comment: Thank you so much! The Framework is .NET 4.5. Doing this I put an image on both screens. Remember that the tablet screen is duplicated from PC screen, so this detects only one.

Comment: Try this thread then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22258906/how-to-detect-duplicated-monitors-as-separate-screens

Comment: With that I can't get a handler to work with the screen. Using this code, I can know how many screen are connected, but no work with them. At least what I've seen

Comment: Hi Ofer! Any help please?